# Network meta-analysis with trials of different follow-up time

Tags: r, meta-analysis, hazard, pooling, network-meta-analysis

0

I am trying to do a network meta-analysis, and calculating anticipated absolute differences, I have seen other papers generating anticipated absolute differences for treatment for x number of years. However the trials that were pooled from studies from different lengths of follow-up time. My current results are in risk ratio format, pooling from different hazard ratio.I was using R gemtc package. How would you standardise the follow-up time as I am trying to get the Absolute risk reduction for the certain follow-up time in order to calculate Numbers needed to treat for certain follow-up time. I am reporting risk ratio, pooling from different hazard ratio.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're pooling are reporting Hazard Ratios or Risk Ratios? Minor note, whether or not you use GRADE methodology is irrelevant to your question on how to pool but I will mention that GRADE does have guidance for assessing the strength/ quality of the evidence from NMAs.